# $A$ open then $B[x,\delta] \subseteq A$

Tags: real-analysis

Let's say $A \in \mathbb{R^p}$ is open. Then for $x \in A$ random there exist an $\delta>0$ so that for every $y \in \mathbb{R^p}$ with $||y-x||<\delta$ , $y \in A$. Now I want to prove that $B[x,\delta] \subseteq A$

I define $B[x,\delta]=\{y \in \mathbb{R^p} | ||y-x|| \leq \delta\}$ and $B(x,\delta)=\{y \in \mathbb{R^p} | ||y-x|| < \delta\}$.

Now it's trivial that for $A$ open , $B(x,\delta) \subseteq A$. But I don't see how I can prove that for $||y-x||=\delta$, $y \in A$.
Can someone help me?

EDIT:  It's not possible to prove what I wanted to prove because it false. We can prove that there always exist an $\delta ' <\delta$ so that $B[x,\delta '] \subseteq A$ with $\delta$ found in the definition of $A$ open. If $\delta' < \delta$ it means that for $||y-x|| <\delta ' <\delta$ so because of the defintion of $A$ open $B(x,\delta') \subset A$ and if we take $||y-x||=\delta' < \delta$ it's the same solution ( we can do the last steps togheter).

Comment: What you ask for is false. What is true is that there exists $\delta' < \delta$ such that $B[x,\delta'] \subset A$.

Comment: that makes more sense

Comment: how Can i prove that?

Comment: nevermind I found it I think, thank you I will edti my question